# How to share Run/Debug Configurations in a version controlled project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

This should be really easy but for some reason I can't get it working. Google/Android Studio guys recommend to avoid having .idea and *.iml files under version control and use "Import project" instead. Works fine, no problem.

However, if I want to share a run/debug configuration, I check the "Share" checkbox in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog which in turn creates .idea/configurations/name.xml. All right, let's put an exception in .gitignore for this file.

Now, what happens:

1. git checkout (gradle files + .idea/configurations/name.xml)
2. Import project (all the .idea and *.iml files are generated)
3. Run -> Edit Configurations... -> do I see the shared configuration there? Nope!

It's because the configuration must be referenced by .idea/workspace.xml file. But everyone recommends to avoid having this file versioned because it contains **user** settings so it should be generated automatically.

So how to solve this chicken-egg problem?

Comment: did you try to write a gradle task for the run configuration?

Comment: @chokdee: I could do that, yes, but my intention is to have it shared in the Android Studio dialog.

Comment: I understand, but if you do it everybody have the possibility to create a run configuration with 2 clicks

Comment: Each time you see such issue it's better to create issue at [google code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry). It is working sometimes and helps google devs to resolve such problems in the future.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230911&thanks=230911&ts=1482501845

Answer (score 2):

For me it was enough to add the "runConfigurations" folder to version control.

All Configurations have to have "Share" checked as to provide a seperate file for them.

Then once project is checked out all configurations are runnable again.

This works perfectly in Android Studio 3.5.3. (With my flutter repository)

Answer (score 2):

While adding run configurations select select `Store as project file`. Then you can commit that file to git.

[image: Store as project file]